# I cant PUT or DELETE anything on my MySQL DB with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, http-delete, http-put

I cant put and delete anything on my database, and i think that my core are correct

This is for a project, running MariaDB 10.1.37, Apache 2.

The code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000;
const mysql = require('mysql');

function execSQLQuery(sqlQry, res){
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'usdb'

});
    connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, results, fields){
        if(error)
            res.json(error);
        else
            res.json(results);
        connection.end();
        console.log('executou!')
    })
}
//cofigurando body parser para pegar os POSTS mais tarde
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//definindo as rotas
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/',(req,res) => res.json({message: 'Funcionando!'}));
app.use('/',router);

router.get('/substances',(req, res) =>{
    execSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM organicssubstances', res);
});

router.get('/substance/:id?', (req, res) =>{
    let filter = '';
    if(req.params.id) filter = ' WHERE id=' + parseInt(req.params.id);
    execSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM organicssubstances"+filter, res);
});

router.get('/substance/:id', (req,res) =>{
    execSQLQuery("DELETE FROM organicssubstances WHERE id=" + parseInt(req.params.id), res);
});

router.get('/substances', (req,res) =>{
    const substance = req.body.substring(0,150);
    const formula = req.body.substring(0,150);
    execSQLQuery(`INSERT INTO organicssubstances(substance, formula) VALUES('${substance}','${formula}')`, res);
});

//inicia o servidor
app.listen(port)
console.log('API Funcionando!')
```

Code of PUT and DELETE:

```
router.get('/substance/:id', (req,res) =>{
    execSQLQuery("DELETE FROM organicssubstances WHERE id=" + parseInt(req.params.id), res);
});

router.get('/substances', (req,res) =>{
    const substance = req.body.substring(0,150);
    const formula = req.body.substring(0,150);
    execSQLQuery(`INSERT INTO organicssubstances(substance, formula) VALUES('${substance}','${formula}')`, res);
});
```

I see this code on a site and just adapted to my use, but not working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzupo.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5KzP.png

Comment: You can use `try()` and `catch()` to give you an error reading

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen, you should define the route as put and delete. Not get

```
router.get(‘/urlforget’, callbackfunction);


router.put(‘/urlforput’, callbackfunction);
```

Comment: so, i use router.put and router.del ?